# Discord.js Mute command only sends embed for incorrect command

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

So im making a mute command for my discord bot which finds if a "Muted" role exists and if it doesn't then the bot creates a "Muted" role and then gives that role to the mentioned member and currently when i run the command it only gives me the embed that its supposed to send if the command was written incorrectly.

```
const BaseCommand = require('../../utils/structures/BaseCommand');
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = class MuteCommand extends BaseCommand {
  constructor() {
    super('mute', 'moderation', []);
  }

  async run(client, message, args) {
    if(!message.member.hasPermission("MUTE_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send("You do not have Permission to use this command.");
    if(!message.guild.me.hasPermission("MUTE_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send("I do not have Permissions to mute members.");
    const Embedhelp = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('Mute Command')
    .setColor('#6DCE75')
    .setDescription('Use this command to Mute a member so that they cannot chat in text channels nor speak in voice channels')
    .addFields(
      { name: '**Usage:**', value: '=mute (user) (time) (reason)'},
      { name: '**Example:**', value: '=mute @Michael stfu'},
      { name: '**Info**', value: 'You cannot mute yourself.\nYou cannot mute me.\nYou cannot mute members with a role higher than yours\nYou cannot mute members that have already been muted'}
   )
    .setFooter(client.user.tag, client.user.displayAvatarURL());

    let role = 'Muted'
    let muterole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(x => x.name === role);
    if (typeof muterole === undefined) {
      message.guild.roles.create({
        data: {
          name: 'muted',
          color: '#ff0000',
          permissions: {
              SEND_MESSAGES: false,
              ADD_REACTIONS: false,
              SPEAK: false
          }
        },
        reason: 'to mute people',
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err).then(message.channel.send('Mute Role could not be created')))
    } 

    const mentionedMember = message.mentions.members.first() || await message.guild.members.fetch(args[0]);
    let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ");
    const banEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
     .setTitle('You have been Muted in '+message.guild.name)
     .setDescription('Reason for Mute: '+reason)
     .setColor('#6DCE75')
     .setTimestamp()
     .setFooter(client.user.tag, client.user.displayAvatarURL());

   if (!reason) reason = 'No reason provided';
   if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send(Embedhelp);
   if (!mentionedMember) return message.channel.send(Embedhelp);
   if (!mentionedMember.bannable) return message.channel.send(Embedhelp);
   if (mentionedMember.user.id == message.author.id) return message.channel.send(Embedhelp);
   if (muterole = undefined) return message.channel.send(Embedhelp);
   if (mentionedMember.user.id == client.user.id) return message.channel.send(Embedhelp);
   if (mentionedMember.roles.cache.has(muterole)) return message.channel.send(Embedhelp);
   if (message.member.roles.highest.position <= mentionedMember.roles.highest.position) return message.channel.send(Embedhelp);

   await mentionedMember.send(banEmbed).catch(err => console.log(err));
   await mentionedMember.roles.add(muterole).catch(err => console.log(err).then(message.channel.send('There was an error while muting the member')))

  } 
}
```

I am still unable to find out what the problem is and why it does this, i would very much like to know the error in my code and if there are any more erros that i am unaware of.

Comment: what situration are you at while testing the command? You're testing the missing role part or what?

Comment: @Bobosky yea im testing the part where the role doesn't exist but instead of creating the role and giving it to the user it just sends the help embed'

Comment: Moved to answer section.

Answer (score 0):

We can see your code:

```js
    let role = 'Muted'
    let muterole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(x => x.name === role);
    if (typeof muterole === undefined) {
      message.guild.roles.create({
        data: {
          name: 'muted',
          color: '#ff0000',
          permissions: {
              SEND_MESSAGES: false,
              ADD_REACTIONS: false,
              SPEAK: false
          }
        },
        reason: 'to mute people',
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err).then(message.channel.send('Mute Role could not be created')))
    } 

if (muterole = undefined) return message.channel.send(Embedhelp);
```

and this will stop the runnning while muterole is undefined.
Since the muterole is not able to create, it will stop running while running to the if muterole line.
To fix the problem, while creating a role in discord.js, permissions flag is needed only when you want to add the permissions to the role. You don't have to put false/deny to specific which permissions you don't want in the role since it's marking all the permissions as false if you don't't label them out.
Therefore, we could replace the permissions with only bracket:

```js
if (muterole === undefined) {
    message.guild.roles.create({
        data: {
            name: 'muted',
            color: '#ff0000',
            permissions: []
        },
        reason: 'to mute people',
    })
        .catch(err => console.log(err).then(message.channel.send('Mute Role could not be created')))
}
```