# Discord Role not getting created

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm making a mute command and for the most part it works, when the 'Muted' role exists it gives it to the member with no problem and everything works out fine, but when the role doesn't exist it gives me the error;

`Supplied roles is not a Role, Snowflake or Array or Collection of Roles or Snowflakes.`

Here is the code:

```
const BaseCommand = require('../../utils/structures/BaseCommand');
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = class MuteCommand extends BaseCommand {
  constructor() {
    super('mute', 'moderation', []);
  }

  async run(client, message, args) {
    if(!message.member.hasPermission("MUTE_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send("You do not have Permission to use this command.");
    if(!message.guild.me.hasPermission("MUTE_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send("I do not have Permissions to mute members.");
    const Embedhelp = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('Mute Command')
    .setColor('#6DCE75')
    .setDescription('Use this command to Mute a member so that they cannot chat in text channels nor speak in voice channels')
    .addFields(
      { name: '**Usage:**', value: '=mute (user) (time) (reason)'},
      { name: '**Example:**', value: '=mute @Michael stfu'},
      { name: '**Info**', value: 'You cannot mute yourself.\nYou cannot mute me.\nYou cannot mute members with a role higher than yours\nYou cannot mute members that have already been muted'}
   )
    .setFooter(client.user.tag, client.user.displayAvatarURL());

    const mentionedMember = message.mentions.members.first() || await message.guild.members.fetch(args[0]);
    let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ");
    const muteEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
     .setTitle('You have been Muted in '+message.guild.name)
     .setDescription('Reason for Mute: '+reason)
     .setColor('#6DCE75')
     .setTimestamp()
     .setFooter(client.user.tag, client.user.displayAvatarURL());

    let role = 'Muted';
    let newrole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(x => x.name === role);
    if (typeof newrole === undefined) {
     await message.guild.roles.create({
        data: {
          name: 'Muted',
          color: '#414247',
          permissions: {
              SEND_MESSAGES: false,
              ADD_REACTIONS: false,
              SPEAK: false
          }
        },
        reason: 'to mute people',
      })
      .catch(console.log(err)); {
        message.channel.send('Could not create muted role');
      };
      if (!reason) reason = 'No reason provided';
      if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send(Embedhelp);
      if (!mentionedMember) return message.channel.send(Embedhelp);
      if (!mentionedMember.bannable) return message.channel.send(Embedhelp);
      if (mentionedMember.user.id == message.author.id) return message.channel.send(Embedhelp);
      if (mentionedMember.user.id == client.user.id) return message.channel.send(Embedhelp);
      if (mentionedMember.roles.cache.find(x => x.name === role)) return message.channel.send(Embedhelp);
      if (message.member.roles.highest.position <= mentionedMember.roles.highest.position) return message.channel.send(Embedhelp);
   
      mendtionedMember.roles.add(newrole)
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err); {
        return message.channel.send('I was unable to mute the user');
        };
      }).then(() => {
        message.channel.send('Successfully Muted '+mentionedMember.user.tag);
      });
    } else {
    if (!reason) reason = 'No reason provided';
    if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send(Embedhelp);
    if (!mentionedMember) return message.channel.send(Embedhelp);
    if (!mentionedMember.bannable) return message.channel.send(Embedhelp);
    if (mentionedMember.user.id == message.author.id) return message.channel.send(Embedhelp);
    if (mentionedMember.user.id == client.user.id) return message.channel.send(Embedhelp);
    if (mentionedMember.roles.cache.find(x => x.name === role)) return message.channel.send(Embedhelp);
    if (message.member.roles.highest.position <= mentionedMember.roles.highest.position) return message.channel.send(Embedhelp);
 
    await mentionedMember.roles
   .add(newrole)
   .catch(err => {
    console.log(err); {
    return message.channel.send('I was unable to mute the user');
    }
  }).then(() => {
    message.channel.send('Successfully Muted '+mentionedMember.user.tag);
  });
    };
  } 
}
```

the part where the role is created is;

```
let newrole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(x => x.name === role);
    if (typeof newrole === undefined) {
     await message.guild.roles.create({
        data: {
          name: 'Muted',
          color: '#414247',
          permissions: {
              SEND_MESSAGES: false,
              ADD_REACTIONS: false,
              SPEAK: false
          }
        },
        reason: 'to mute people',
      })
      .catch(console.log(err)); {
        message.channel.send('Could not create muted role');
      };
```

it checks if the Muted role already exists and then if it doesn't it creates a Muted role, I am not sure if the error originates here but I believe that it fails to create the role which is why it doesn't exist and it cannot give it to the mentioned user, if there is anyway to fix this please let me know.

Comment: You were already answered in your previous question. You need to handle the promise for `GuildRoleManager#create()`,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.js Error Supplied roles is not a Role, Snowflake or Array or Collection of Roles or Snowflakes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67114441/discord-js-error-supplied-roles-is-not-a-role-snowflake-or-array-or-collection)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why are you making a new post about the same question as I **have already** answered your question with clear instruction on your previous post created yesterday. Here is the [answer for the question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67110982/13713418)

Comment: After i tried your soloution it fixed the part where it wouldnt create the role, but it still gives me the same error